# Static block in Vue

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component

I have come across vue code that I have never seen before

```
export default {
  name: "mycomponent",
  static: {
    mystaticvar: 2
  },
  data() {
    return {

    }
```

With **mystaticvar** accessed with **this.$options.static.mystaticvar**

The question I have is what is the point of this pattern? What does it offer over putting it in 'data'.

Comment: If I had to guess, it does not become reactive. But why not just declare `const mystaticvar` outside the component in that case.